# Python Strings not matching

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python, trying to calculate some time, get two strings from different sources to be equal, but the are FALSE, when tested.  First string is pulled sliced from a single line file, the other is set as a variable in the code.  Both show as str, same apparent value, but when checked to be equal, they are FALSE.

```
from datetime import datetime

file=open("test.db","r")

for i in file:
    print(i)
    print(repr(i))
    print(str(i.rstrip('\n')))
    ci_time = (str((i.rstrip('\n'))[14:20]))
    print(ci_time)
ci_time1 = '08:00'

print(type(ci_time))
print(ci_time)
print(type(ci_time1))
print(ci_time1)
print(ci_time == ci_time1)

file.close()




Here is my output...
$ python3 test.py
CI 2018-11-23 08:00 CO 2018-11-23 17:00

'CI 2018-11-23 08:00 CO 2018-11-23 17:00\n'
CI 2018-11-23 08:00 CO 2018-11-23 17:00
08:00
<class 'str'>
08:00
<class 'str'>

08:00
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you look carefully you will see that your `ci_time` variable actually has a trailing space:

```
ci_time

>>'08:00 '
```

You can remove this using:

```
ci_time.strip()
>>'08:00'
```

Or alternatively you can update the index in your string slice to be `[14:19]`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried it from the interpreter (lesson learned).  I updated the slicing, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `strip()` to `ci_time` as given below, you need to strip the space in `ci_time`.

```
print(ci_time.strip() == ci_time1)

ci = 'CI 2018-11-23 08:00 CO 2018-11-23 17:00'
print len(str(ci[14:20])) --6
print len(str(ci[14:20]).strip()) --5
```